# Local Machine Blocked via Windows Firewall Still Has Access to Share

Tags: windows-10, lan, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 10 machine on a LAN (the "Server").  This machine has a share that anyone on the LAN can access.  I want to prevent one specific machine on the LAN from accessing this share.  The LAN IP address of the machine to be excluded from accessing the share is 192.168.42.150.  This machine is a laptop and is connected to the LAN via WiFi.  There is no wired connection to the LAN.

I created a "brute force" Inbound firewall rule:

```
Profile:                     private
Enabled:                     yes
Action:                      Block
Override:                    No
Program:                     Any
Local Address:               192.168.42.150
Remote Address:              Any
Protocol:                    Any
Local Port:                  Any
Remote Port:                 Any
Authorized Computers:        Any
Authorized Local Principals: Any
Local User Owner:            Any
Application Package:         Any
```

The "brute force" nature of this rule lies in my blocking any port, not just those associated with Windows shares.  Why is the machine whose LAN IP is 192.168.42.150 still able to browse and access all the shares on the Server whose firewall settings are specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machine you are attempting to block is the remote machine in this scenario, not the local one. So you need to set Remote Address, not Local Address, to 192.168.42.150.